# Matplotlib with cygwin is not installed successfully

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, cygwin

```
s9kumar@N-20L6PF146CTG ~
$ easy_install-3.6 pip
WARNING: The easy_install command is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 21.1.1
Adding pip 21.1.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/bin
Installing pip3 script to /usr/bin
Installing pip3.6 script to /usr/bin

Using /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip

s9kumar@N-20L6PF146CTG ~
$ pip install --upgrade six
Collecting six
  Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Installing collected packages: six
Successfully installed six-1.16.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

s9kumar@N-20L6PF146CTG ~
$ pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-3.3.4.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 37.9 MB 4.6 MB/s
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3.6 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wc_8xx_x/matplotlib_8ddd887eddef4dd5b6b0855797588ffb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-wc_8xx_x/matplotlib_8ddd887eddef4dd5b6b0855797588ffb/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-g2a0peyk
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-wc_8xx_x/matplotlib_8ddd887eddef4dd5b6b0855797588ffb/
 Complete output (3243 lines):
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp06rrfkhl
             cwd: /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c
        Complete output (261 lines):
        Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
        Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
        Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
        Cythonizing sources
        blas_opt_info:
        blas_mkl_info:
        customize UnixCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blis_info:
          libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_info:
          libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_info:
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        accelerate_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blas_info:
          libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blas_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

          NOT AVAILABLE

        non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
        lapack_opt_info:
        lapack_mkl_info:
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_lapack_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_clapack_info:
          libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        flame_info:
          libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_info:
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_info:
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        lapack_info:
          libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        lapack_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

          NOT AVAILABLE

        numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
          FOUND:
            language = c
            define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

        running dist_info
        running build_src
        build_src
        building py_modules sources
        creating build
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/distutils
        building library "npymath" sources
        Could not locate executable g77
        Could not locate executable f77
        Could not locate executable ifort
        Could not locate executable ifl
        Could not locate executable f90
        Could not locate executable efl
        Could not locate executable gfortran
        Could not locate executable f95
        Could not locate executable g95
        don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h
          adding 'build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
        None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
        building library "npysort" sources
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h
          adding 'build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/timsort.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/binsearch.c
        None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h', 'build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h']
        building library "npyrandom" sources
        building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/multiarray
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c
        building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
        Running from numpy source directory.
        setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
          run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
        /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
            Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
            Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
            A better performance should be easily gained by switching
            Blas library.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
            the BLAS environment variable.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
            the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
            the LAPACK environment variable.
          return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
            the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
          return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
          warnings.warn(msg)
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
            main()
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
            return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-87dqkei5/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
            self.run_setup()
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-87dqkei5/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 249, in run_setup
            self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-87dqkei5/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
            exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
          File "setup.py", line 508, in <module>
            setup_package()
          File "setup.py", line 500, in setup_package
            setup(**metadata)
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
            return old_setup(**new_attr)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-87dqkei5/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 165, in setup
            return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
            dist.run_commands()
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-87dqkei5/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 31, in run
            egg_info.run()
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 24, in run
            self.run_command("build_src")
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
            self.distribution.run_command(command)
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 144, in run
            self.build_sources()
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 161, in build_sources
            self.build_extension_sources(ext)
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 318, in build_extension_sources
            sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_aacd30ad84a941fb95ddad32b5118c4c/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
            source = func(extension, build_dir)
          File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 436, in generate_config_h
            moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
          File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 47, in check_types
            out = check_types(*a, **kw)
          File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 294, in check_types
            "install {0}-dev|{0}-devel.".format(python))
        SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
        ----------------------------------------
    WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/60/3f0fe5b7675a461d96b9d6729beecd3532565743278a9c3fe6dd09697fa7/numpy-1.19.5.zip#sha256=a76f502430dd98d7546e1ea2250a7360c065a5fdea52b2dffe8ae7180909b6f4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp06rrfkhl Check the logs for full command output.
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpayemfnwh
             cwd: /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_9baa8a518c1346a9ae3f1f10d05127bf
        Complete output (261 lines):
        Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
        Processing numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
        Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
        Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
        Cythonizing sources
        blas_opt_info:
        blas_mkl_info:
        customize UnixCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blis_info:
          libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_info:
          libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_info:
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        accelerate_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blas_info:
          libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blas_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

          NOT AVAILABLE

        non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
        lapack_opt_info:
        lapack_mkl_info:
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_lapack_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_clapack_info:
          libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        flame_info:
          libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_info:
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_info:
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        lapack_info:
          libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        lapack_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

          NOT AVAILABLE

        numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
          FOUND:
            language = c
            define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

        running dist_info
        running build_src
        build_src
        building py_modules sources
        creating build
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/distutils
        building library "npymath" sources
        Could not locate executable g77
        Could not locate executable f77
        Could not locate executable ifort
        Could not locate executable ifl
        Could not locate executable f90
        Could not locate executable efl
        Could not locate executable gfortran
        Could not locate executable f95
        Could not locate executable g95
        don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h
          adding 'build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
        None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
        building library "npysort" sources
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h
          adding 'build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/timsort.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/npysort/binsearch.c
        None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h', 'build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h']
        building library "npyrandom" sources
        building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
        creating build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/multiarray
        conv_template:> build/src.cygwin-3.3.1-x86_64-3.6/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c
        building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
        Running from numpy source directory.
        setup.py:480: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
          run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
        /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_9baa8a518c1346a9ae3f1f10d05127bf/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
            Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
            Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
            A better performance should be easily gained by switching
            Blas library.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_9baa8a518c1346a9ae3f1f10d05127bf/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
            the BLAS environment variable.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_9baa8a518c1346a9ae3f1f10d05127bf/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
            the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_9baa8a518c1346a9ae3f1f10d05127bf/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
            the LAPACK environment variable.
          return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        /tmp/pip-wheel-yxvf5o0k/numpy_9baa8a518c1346a9ae3f1f10d05127bf/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
            the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
          return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
          warnings.warn(msg)
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
            main()
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
            return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-uugu1akt/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
            self.run_setup()
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-uugu1akt/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 249, in run_setup
            self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-uugu1akt/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
            exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
          File "setup.py", line 508, in <module>
            setup_package()
          File "setup.py", line 500, in setup_package
            setup(**metadata)
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-
```

Comment: any reason to not use the already available `python38-matplotlib` cygwin package with python3.8 ?  https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/python38-matplotlib.html

Comment: Too general title of your question. Include some reference to a version. End of Review.

Answer (score 0):

To install pip, you need to have `python3-setuptools`installed. Then using the `easy_install3 pip` command you can install pip.

After that, you need to have `liblapack-devel` and `libopenblas` installed via Cygwin’s package manager (SciPy depends on them). You also need to have `gcc-fortran`, `python-gtk2`, `tcl-tk`, `libpng`, `pkg-config` and a bunch of other stuff (that pip installer complains about) installed. The dependencies that pip complains about are straightforward (just mark them for installation in Cygwin’s installer).

Running `pip -v install matplotlib` should get you those packages without much headache. you can read this Artical for more understanding

https://www.codefull.net/2015/12/installing-scipy-numpy-and-matplotlib-under-cygwin/